# Solr Fuzzy search in multiValued field with max distance between terms

Tags: solr, lucene, fuzzy-search

Hello stackOverflowers

I have a field in a Solr document collection with a field called
names_txt - this is a multiValue="true" field.

This field contains all the names of the associated persons to a document

I want to be able to both do a fuzzy search and at the same time limit the number of terms between the to matching terms.

The query

```
names_txt:("markus foss"~2)
```

Will return all documents where you find the terms *markus* and *foss* where theres max 2 terms between them.

But when i search in a fuzzy way AND want to also specify the max number of terms between the matches, I cant get the syntax right.

The query:

```
names_txt:(markus~0.7 foss~0.7)
```

This does work, but returns false postives, since it will return a document with "markus something" in one value, and "foss somethingElse" in another.

What I would like to write is:

```
(markus~0.7 foss~0.7)~2
```

- but this syntax is illegal in solr.

Anyone out there have a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Since in one single query term Solr can either process a word distance restraint or a fuzzy search restraint, we will need two terms for this:

```
names_txt:("markus foss"~2) AND names_txt:(markus~0.7 foss~0.7)
```

Note that quantifying fuzzyness by a float number is deprecated. Internally, lucene converts converts the `float` number to an `int` between 0 and 2 anyway, so we should use this integer (Damereau Levenshtein) edit distance right from the beginning in our search terms. So my final proposal states:

```
names_txt:("markus foss"~2) AND names_txt:(markus~1 foss~1)
```

(For those who are interested: The deprecated, somewhat quirky function that converts the similarity `float` to an edit distance `int` can be found at the end of [this code file](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/b6fd1cf3fc4ac4ca0da08cdca62ba5b85fc958bd/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/FuzzyQuery.java).)

Comment: Does this really help? It looks for the _exact_ words "markus" and "foss" within 2-word distance. Hence, the additional fuzzy condition no longer has an effect.

Comment: Any idea why it is deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do that using [SpanQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanQuery.html) The issue is that the usual query parsers in Solr dont support them. Look at [this article](http://searchhub.org/dev/2009/07/18/the-spanquery/) that mentions those that support spans: Surround, Xml-Query-Parser and Qsol. But check the status of each in current solr version.